# Create json rest api without writing or integrating any code

Tags: java, json, rest

I've 2 questions about Java Rest APIs

1'st:

I would like to create a Rest API  with Java Servlets for using in the mobile applications(IOS and Android)
and before doing that I would like to clarify the rest api content. However as much as I search through google all I found was automatic API creators from your Java code. But what I want is different first I want to document our Json Rest API so mobile and server developers can start to work independently. 
Do you know any tool for that?

2'nd:
What I want to achive in our java server application is simple. Get simple json requests from mobile clients and do some database query and respond back with simple json objects.
For achiving this do I need to use any additional Rest API framework such as spring mvc (or something else) or just using Java Servlets and parse the request in doPost method and respond it there
Which one do you suggest?
Thanks

Comment: 1) Swagger 2) Spring Data Rest

Answer (score 1):

Restlet Studio (http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-studio) or APISpark (http://restlet.com/products/apispark/) can bring you what you expect.

Restlet Studio allows you to define / design you API with a Web IDE: resources and their methods, representations (exchanged data structures). You can then have access to corresponding Swagger content and generate online client SDKs and even server skeletons for your API (this is internally based on Swagger Codegen)...

To implement your RESTful applications, Restlet can help you. It's a Java REST framework to access and / or implement RESTful applications. Restlet can be used within a servlet container with its servlet extension (see this link https://github.com/restlet/restlet-tutorial/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.tutorial.markdown/02_Server_Side/04_Server_Deployment/02_Servlet_Deployment.md).

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: I didn't know Restlet, seems very interesting

Answer (score 0):

I aggree with Stephan comment.

With `Spring Boot` and `Spring Data Rest`, the only code you will need to write is the mapping between your DB and your DAO Entities.

To document your API *before* writing it, you can use in fact any regular tools.
REST APIs don't have anything specific compared to others APIs to be documented.
Much of the documentation of APIs I've written were using `Ms-Word`...

`Swagger` provide a Json syntax to document a REST API, but it is mainly useful when used with `Swagger-Ui`, which allow to request the deployed server dynamically. You can use Swagger for your documentation, but as there will be no already existing server, I'm not sure it is worth the cost of learning its syntax. The main benefits is to give you constraints (like predefined fields) to follow.

By the way, I think that writing a REST Api Mapping or just document it takes the same amount of time, so I'm not sure it is really worth making all the documentation in a stand-alone way.

Comment: lets assume that I'm going to choose spring data rest , does it work with Google Cloud App Engine(Because of the url mappings etc..) or should I have to use something different on cloud

Comment: I can't answer, I don't know Google Cloud App Engine. There is plenty of example on the web for you to see the syntax of the mapping produce by Spring Data Rest. This is also configurable by anotation, but as you don't want to write any code...